# Why is my btrfs/dm-crypt RAID1 setup so slow?

Tags: io, btrfs, hard-drive

I have a system that's set up with a four-disk RAID1 array based on btrfs. Two disks are 1TB traditional HDDs, and the other two are 128GB SSDs. Most of each disk is filled up with a LUKS container. Inside all four LUKS containers I have a single btrfs filesystem that does the RAID1.

The above configuration *should* get pretty decent performance, but unfortunately, it's super slow. Here are some benchmarks, run generally around the same time:

```
% dd if=/dev/zero of=tmpfile bs=1M count=1024
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB) copied, 1.18302 s, 908 MB/s
% dd if=/dev/zero of=tmpfile bs=1M count=1024
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB) copied, 1.66737 s, 644 MB/s
% dd if=tmpfile of=/dev/null bs=1M count=1024     
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB) copied, 1.61369 s, 665 MB/s
% echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches > /dev/null
% dd if=tmpfile of=/dev/null bs=1M count=1024
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB) copied, 8.05449 s, 133 MB/s
% echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches > /dev/null
% dd if=/dev/zero of=tmpfile bs=1M count=1024           
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB) copied, 2.66874 s, 402 MB/s
% echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches > /dev/null
% dd if=tmpfile of=/dev/null bs=1M count=1024           
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB) copied, 5.164 s, 208 MB/s
```

Not really sure what to make of them, but the disk certainly *seems* slow. And generally when I look at `iotop`, I see write throughputs of 5-10 MB/s or so. Not so great.

Here's some more info:

```
% cryptsetup benchmark
# Tests are approximate using memory only (no storage IO).
PBKDF2-sha1       834853 iterations per second
PBKDF2-sha256     548418 iterations per second
PBKDF2-sha512     366122 iterations per second
PBKDF2-ripemd160  508031 iterations per second
PBKDF2-whirlpool  175229 iterations per second
#  Algorithm | Key |  Encryption |  Decryption
     aes-cbc   128b   379.4 MiB/s  1552.0 MiB/s
 serpent-cbc   128b    49.3 MiB/s   216.5 MiB/s
 twofish-cbc   128b   129.3 MiB/s   258.3 MiB/s
     aes-cbc   256b   325.3 MiB/s  1158.4 MiB/s
 serpent-cbc   256b    65.0 MiB/s   213.1 MiB/s
 twofish-cbc   256b   136.3 MiB/s   259.8 MiB/s
     aes-xts   256b  1326.8 MiB/s  1333.5 MiB/s
 serpent-xts   256b   224.4 MiB/s   216.7 MiB/s
 twofish-xts   256b   255.5 MiB/s   257.2 MiB/s
     aes-xts   512b  1034.8 MiB/s  1009.7 MiB/s
 serpent-xts   512b   225.8 MiB/s   214.1 MiB/s
 twofish-xts   512b   255.1 MiB/s   257.1 MiB/s
% lsmod | grep aes  
aesni_intel           167936  18 
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
lrw                    16384  5 serpent_sse2_x86_64,aesni_intel,serpent_avx_x86_64,twofish_avx_x86_64,twofish_x86_64_3way
glue_helper            16384  5 serpent_sse2_x86_64,aesni_intel,serpent_avx_x86_64,twofish_avx_x86_64,twofish_x86_64_3way
ablk_helper            16384  4 serpent_sse2_x86_64,aesni_intel,serpent_avx_x86_64,twofish_avx_x86_64
cryptd                 20480  9 ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel,ablk_helper
% uname -a
Linux steevie 4.7.0-0.bpo.1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.7.5-1~bpo8+1 (2016-09-30) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

As you can see, I'm on Debian 8 running a kernel from `jessie-backports`.

Also, at the suggestion of https://askubuntu.com/questions/246102/slow-ssd-dm-crypt-with-luks-encryption-in-ubuntu-12-10, I had the initramfs load the `cryptd`, `aes_x86_64`, and `aesni_intel` modules during early boot. However, rebooting and benchmarking again gave almost the exact same speed.

Any idea where this terrible performance could be coming from?

Comment: Using `dd` in the manner you did only tests how well a system performs when doing streaming IO, with little to no seeking for the disk heads on a physical disk.  5-10 MB/sec is suspiciously just about what a consumer-grade SATA disk that can do at most 60-70 random IO operations/sec will can support if the amount of data transferred between disk head seeks averages 128 kB.